# Regex get specific part of string after the nth "$" delimiter, js

Tags: javascript, regex, string, discord.js, match

So I have this for a discord command.

> $command this my first text $ this is my second text $ this is my
> third text $ this is my fourth text

I need to get for example the third text part, and it should output like this: **this is my third text**. Removing the other text.

So it should be something like this.

1. Get the third occurrence of **$**.
2. Remove the rest of the text: **$command this my first text $ this is my second text $** and **$ this is my fourth text**
3. Get the **this is my third text** part.

How do you do that in regex? I searched the threads here and some said to use something like a capture group, but I couldn't make it work.

```
(?:\$){2}(\s.*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\$[^$]+` to match `$` followed by other characters.

```js
let s = '$command this my first text $ this is my second text $ this is my third text $ this is my fourth text';
let res = s.match(/(?:\$[^$]+){2}\$([^$]+)/)[1].trim();
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a capture group:

```
^(?:[^$]*\$){3}\s*([^$]*[^\s$])
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

  - `[^$]*\$` Match optional chars other than `$` and then match `$`
- `){3}`  Close the non capture group and repeat it 3 times
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^$]*` Match optional chars other than `$`
  - `[^\s$]` Match a non whitespace character other than `$`
- `)` Close group 1

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a2eO8G/1).

```js
const s = "$command this my first text $ this is my second text $ this is my third text $ this is my fourth text";
const regex = /^(?:[^$]*\$){3}\s*([^$]*[^\s$])/;
const m = s.match(regex);
if (m) console.log(m[1])
```

Using a lookbehind assertion if that is [supported](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) to get a match only:

```js
const s = "$command this my first text $ this is my second text $ this is my third text $ this is my fourth text";
const regex = /(?<=^(?:[^$]*\$){3}\s*)[^\s$](?:[^$]*[^\s$])?/;
const m = s.match(regex);
if (m) console.log(m[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let s = '$command this my first text $ this is my second text $ this is my third text $ this is my fourth text';
let res = s.match(/(?<=((?<=\$).*?\$){2}) this is my.*?(?=\$)/)[0];
console.log(res);
```

The library should accept positive lookahead and lookbehind so you could try this:

```
(?<=((?<=\$).*?\$){2}) this is my.*?(?=\$)
```